# Toggle ImageView Button inside custom listview

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-studio, adapter

I have a List view of ringtones with a play image view in each row for each ringtone ..

This is the view of it..

[image: This is the view of it]

Now obviously when user clicks on a play button it should switch into pause button.. I have implemented this and it's all good so far :

**Interface**(In adapter)

```
       public interface PlayPauseClick {
         void playPauseOnClick(int position);
        }
   private PlayPauseClick callback;
   public void setPlayPauseClickListener(PlayPauseClick listener) {
        this.callback = listener;
    }
```

**Adapter**(In getView)

```
    Product product = (Product) mDataItems.get(position);
    holder.playPause=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.playPause); 
    holder.playPause.setImageResource(product.getPlayPauseId());
    holder.playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              if (callback != null) {
                  callback.playPauseOnClick(position);
              }      
        }
    });
```

**Activity**

```
    @Override
public void playPauseOnClick(int position) {
    final Product product = productList.get(position);
                if (product.paused) {
                    product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    product.paused=false;
                }else {
                    product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
                    product.paused = true;
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
    };
```

Now I have a problem :

I don't know how to track the currently playing row,I mean if user wants to play a song from another row, first I have to change currently pause toggle to play, then play the new one.

Can you help me with this please !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found Two answers..

## 1: We can store the index of the current song which is played in the adapter.

So we just need to turn on pause when we click on an other button.

**In Adapter :**

```
   int currentPosition = -1;
...
if (callback != null) {
  callback.playPauseOnClick(position);
  if (currentPosition == -1){
       currentPosition = position;
  } else if (currentPosition == position){
       currentPosition = -1;
  } else if (currentPosition != -1 && currentPosition != position){
       callback.playPauseOnClick(currentPosition);
       currentPosition = position;
  }
}
```

## 2: Set resources for every listview data item

inside callback or anywhere can get listview data:

```
@Override
public void playPauseOnClick(int position) {
    final Product product = productList.get(position);
    if (product.paused) {
        for(int i=0;i< productList.size();i++)
        {
            movieList.get(i).setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
            movieList.get(i).paused = true;
        }
        product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        product.paused=false;
    }else {
        product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
        product.paused = true;
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hold a variable "mCurrentPosition" to hold the currently playing track.

Then create two separate methods, one for play and one for pause. Simply pause the current track and play the one that was clicked.

Remember to also set the current position when you play a new track.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
      if (callback != null) {
          callback.pause(mCurrentPosition);
          mCurrentPosition = position;
          callback.play(position);
      }      
}
```

You may need to adjust it a bit as I don't know how you've setup your "callback" or where "position" is coming from. I'm assuming something like "getAdapterPosition()". But hopefully you can see how to do it by this example. If not please comment.

**Edit** in response to updated question:

For the interface do something like this:

```
public interface PlayPauseClick {
    void pause(int position);
    void play(int position);
}
```

**Edit2**:

```
@Override
void pause(int position) {
    if(position != null) {
        Product product = productList.get(position);
        product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
        product.paused = true;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
void play(int position) {
    // Homework exercise.
}
```

Comment: This is the write answer.

Comment: I've updated my question .. Can you please explain more about what changes should I make in my play and pause method(How to separate them) ..

Comment: I meant changes in my orginal playPauseOnClick method .. about condition and so on ..

Comment: Ok how about that? Does that clear things up now? It might not be exactly correct for your code but can you see how to do it now?

Comment: I understand how your solution works , but things doesn't add up there , But I'm working on it .. I let you know , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this
first, declare a global variable

```
int lastposition=null;
```

then

```
 @Override
public void playPauseOnClick(int position) {
    final Product product = productList.get(position);
                if(lastposition!=null)
                {
                     Product previous = productList.get(lastposition);
                     previous.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                     previous.paused=false;
                     lastposition=position;
                } else lastposition=position;
                if (product.paused) {
                    //new loadSingleView().execute(product.image_url);
                    //Log.d(LOG, product.image_url);
                    product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    product.paused=false;
                }else {
                    product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
                    product.paused = true;
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
    };
```

Replace the above code with code in your activity